# Getting to the Dashboard in Lion

Tags: macos

I'm trying to decide whether or not to upgrade to Lion.  I use the Dashboard a *lot*, and I value the ability to get to it quickly by hitting the button on my keyboard.  In Lion, it sounds like I would have to open Mission Control, then use my mouse to open the Dashboard.

Is this the only way to get to the Dashboard in Lion?  Does the old keyboard button still work?  If not, can I set a keyboard shortcut to open it without going through Mission Control first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this:

[image]

so, hotkey for dashboard is working.

Answer (score 5):

By default the Dashboard is on its own space, always the leftmost one. The Dashboard button still works and makes you jump right there.

Alternatively, you can disable this behavior in the General preference pane and revert to the Dashboard as an overlay, just as it was before Lion.

Answer (score 0):

My new MacBook Air's keyboard doesn't HAVE a Dashboard button, it was replaced by a Launchpad button, and I hate Launchpad.

So I installed KeyRemap4MacBook: http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/
And that allowed me to swap the Launchpad key's functionality.  Now it launches Dashboard instead.  Happy!